# looping through a table and storing a particular cell in an array if row is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I currently have a table that is triggered by a drop down. Inside the table, there's a checkbox. When the check box is checked and the user clicks on the confirm button, the code should loop through the table and get the email values of all the checked rows and store them in an array. So far, it can check if the rows are checked. I've found a few ways online but its not working. Here's the table:

```
    <?php if ($picked != null){ ;
      foreach ($picked as $rows): ?> 
        echo base_url(); ?>employer/view/send/<?php echo $rows['username']; ?>-->
      <!--form action="" method="POST"--> 
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <table id="view_add" 
        class="table dataTable table-striped table-dynamic table-hover _tm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
              style="width: 250px;">
              Applicant Name
            </th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
              style="width: 200px;">
              Employer
            </th>
            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
              style="width: 200px;">
              Post Header
            </th>
            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
              style="width: 450px;">
              Description
            </th>
            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
              style="width: 100px;">
              VIEW CV
            </th>
            <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" 
              style="width: 100px;">
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php foreach ($picked as $rows): ?> 
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows['applicantName']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['employerName']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['postingName']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['postDescription']; ?></td>
            <td style="display: none;"><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
            <td><a id="stress" data-toggle="modal" href="#editButton" 
              data-full="<?php echo $rows['fullName']; ?>" 
              data-school="<?php echo $rows['institution']; ?>" 
              data-state="<?php echo $rows['state']; ?>" 
              data-location="<?php echo $rows['location']; ?>" 
              data-dob="<?php echo $rows['dob']; ?>" data-skill="<?php echo $rows['skills']; ?>" 
              data-sex="<?php echo $rows['sex']; ?>" data-gpa="<?php echo $rows['cgpa']; ?>" 
              data-call="<?php echo $rows['phone']; ?>" 
              data-like="<?php echo $rows['favoured']; ?>" 
              data-award="<?php echo $rows['awards']; ?>" 
              data-interest="<?php echo $rows['interests']; ?>" class="myeditButton"
            >view</a></td>
            <td>
              <label class="switch m-r-40">
                <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" 
                  id="<?php echo $rows['applicationKey']?>" 
                  data-mail="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>" 
                  data-confirm="<?php echo $rows['applicationId']; ?>" 
                  id="check" name="check" <?php echo $rows['status'] ? 'checked':''; ?> >
                <span class="switch-label" data-on="yes" data-off="no"></span>
                <span class="switch-handle"></span>
              </label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm" id="mail" class="btn btn-primary mail">
      </div>
    <!--/form-->
 <?php }else{ ;?>
   <div class="alert alert-warning">
     <h4>There are no current Applicants for this post.</h4>
   </div>'
   <?php } ;?>
```

Here's the little script I've used:

```
    <script>
$(document).on("click", "#mail", function () //<-small mistake here
{
   var mail_list = [];
   $( 'input[type=checkbox]:checked' ).each(
        function(){
            var mail = $(this).data("mail");

            mail_list.push(mail);

            var emailers = mail_list.join(",");

//SEND TO PHP
           $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>employer/view/send',
           data: {
                     chosen: emailers
                    },
           success: function( data ) {
                     console.log( data );
                    }
           }); 
            //the END
        }
    )
});
</script>
```

My JS isn't so good.

Lastly, heres the php end

```
else if ($param1 == 'send') 
        {

        $src1= $_POST['chosen'];
        $array = explode(",", $src1);

        print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should add a way to "find" the email value of a row. So edit the html with something like that :

```
<td style="display: none;" class="email-value">
    <?php echo $rows['email']; ?>
</td>
```

Now, I think there is a small error in your code, an html `id` is targetable by `#` and a `class` by a `.`. So with my changement I propose :

```
$(document).on("click", "#mail", function () //<-small mistake here
{
   var mail_list = [];
   $( 'input[type=checkbox]:checked' ).each(
        function(){
            var mail = $(this).parents("tr").find(".email-value").text();
            //this line search the "tr" parent of each input checkbox that's checked, 
            //and then finds the child "email" value of it.
            mail_list.push(mail);
        }
    )
})
```

---

***Alter solution***

Add the email in data parameters of the checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" 
              id="<?php echo $rows['applicationKey']?>" 
              data-mail="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>" 
              data-confirm="<?php echo $rows['applicationId']; ?>" 
              data-email="<?= $rows['email']"
              id="check" name="check" <?php echo $rows['status'] ? 'checked':''; ?> >
```

Then, the javascript become quite simple :

```
$(document).on("click", "#mail", function () //<-small mistake here
{
   var mail_list = [];
   $( 'input[type=checkbox]:checked' ).each(
        function(){
            var mail = $(this).data("email");

            mail_list.push(mail);
            //the END
        }
    )
})
```

**update** : oops, it's `parents`*, `parent` can't go upper than one level...

**update2** : Add an alternative version, simplified

Comment: Just keep in mind that an ID (`#something`) can only be used once per document/page, whereas a class (`.something`) can be reused. (Using an ID in multiple places will usually result in only one matching item being selected, which might not be what you expect.)

Comment: @AgiHammerthief In my opinion OP made it better you should not hide email in other html elements but get it from inside checkbox (OP did it by putting email inside 'data-mail') this is better solution then looking for it inside "td" with specially crafted selector. Even better solution would be to put email address inside checkbox value so you can access it from PHP after form submission

Comment: I agree, he can just pass the email in data-email of the checkbox

Comment: Hello, so my js isn't great but will the "var mail" hold all the email values? After that step I'd be posting to a controller and looping through to send something to each email. Thanks. Also, thanks!!! Your solutions working so far.

Comment: Now, you have `mail_list` which contains all the mail of the selected checkbox :]

Comment: Okay, I'll see if it works and get back asap. Thanks

Comment: @Eiji I've made an update to the post, You've answered my question. Thanks. Any idea how i send to php effectively. Just not working.

Comment: To "send" javascript data "to the" php, you only have one way to do that, it's with Ajax. With codeigniter, the best way is to create a new method in your controller. This method will receive data from post data. Then you can easily stock them or do whatever you want with it. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".mail", function ()
{
    var emailList = [];
    var selectedRows = $( 'table._tm' ).find( 'tbody' ) // select table body and
        .find( 'tr' ) // select all rows that has
        .has( 'input[type=checkbox]:checked' ) // checked checkbox element

          selectedRows.each(function(idx, elem) {
              var email = jQuery(elem).find('input[type="checkbox"]').data("mail");
               emailList.push(email);
          });
          console.log( 'elem:', emailList );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite easy try something like this:

```
var emailList = [];

selectedRows.forEach(function(idx, elem) {
    var email = jQuery(elem).data("mail");
    emailList.push(email);
});
```